# Javascript - Fill HTML table on PDF with Woocommerce order table data

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'm developing a way to export Woocommerce order data into a PDF doc table, using javascript.
For that I'm storing the innerText values of each order table cell in different  `let` variables and later
use those variables to populate a HTML table which will appear in my final PDF doc.

I feel like I'm close to hitting gold, but I get a console error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined` on browser.

This is my code so far, any idea why I'm getting this error and any way I could fix it?

```js
function printData(){
    let orderTableData = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce_order_items")[0].innerHTML;
    let orderTableSize = document.getElementById("order_line_items"); 
    let tamanho = orderTableSize.rows.length;
    let orderPricesData = document.getElementsByClassName("wc-order-totals")[0].innerHTML;
    let orderItemName = document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerText;
    let orderItemPrice = document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("item_cost")[0].innerText;
    let orderItemQtd = document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("quantity")[0].innerText;
    let orderItemTotal = document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("line_cost")[0].innerText;

    for(var j = 0; j <= tamanho; j++){
        window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = "<table border='1' width='100%'><tr><th>Item</th><th>Preço uni.</th><th>Qtd.</th><th>Total</th></tr><tr><td>" + document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("name")[j].innerText + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("item_cost")[j].innerText + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("quantity")[j].innerText + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("line_cost")[j].innerText + "</td></tr></table>";    
    }
                 
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
}
```

I'll also leave a print of the Woocommerce table I'm using for test.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you don't need to use the condition `<=` (less than or equal) because you are begining with 0 (because its a array index), just use `<` (less than) in these cases.

Another thing, You should use a iframe to put the content you want to print, I didn't understand the window.frames logic you used.

I tested that snippet and it works:

```
function printData(){
     let orderTableData = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce_order_items")[0].innerHTML;
     let orderTableSize = document.getElementById("order_line_items"); 
     let tamanho = orderTableSize.rows.length;
     let orderPricesData = document.getElementsByClassName("wc-order-totals")[0].innerHTML;
     let orderItemName = document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerText;
     let orderItemPrice = document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("item_cost")[0].innerText;
     let orderItemQtd = document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("quantity")[0].innerText;
     let orderItemTotal = document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("line_cost")[0].innerText;

     let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

     document.body.appendChild(iframe);

     iframe.style.display = 'none';
 
     for(var j = 0; j < tamanho; j++){
        iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = "<table border='1' width='100%'><tr><th>Item</th><th>Preço uni.</th><th>Qtd.</th><th>Total</th></tr><tr><td>" + document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("name")[j].innerText + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("item_cost")[j].innerText + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("quantity")[j].innerText + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("order_line_items").getElementsByClassName("line_cost")[j].innerText + "</td></tr></table>";   
     }
             
     iframe.contentWindow.focus();
     iframe.contentWindow.print();
     document.body.removeChild(iframe);
}
```